Prohibited by secure boot policy
I recently changed my Bootscreen from Gnome.org/Grub themes and after everything installed and successfully completed. I booted my system where my boot screen has successfully changed and when I open my GRUB Command line in that screen and type a command it says

Prohibited by secure boot policy.

(as I wanted to know my boot screen resolution, I typed videoinfo).
I would like to know what does it mean and why my secure boot policy wont allow my system to execute commands.(as a beginner in PC World I would like to know everything even some blogs would be helpful).

Basic starting point is knowing what OS/release you're using; GRUB has different defaults set by version, with Ubuntu carrying patches that simplify grub's behavior (2.06 & newer) where dual boot is detected as being used (at install time), but we don't know what you're using. If you install with Secure Boot enabled then secure boot is fully setup, if you install with it disabled it isn't setup & errors can be expected...  We don't even know what you're running yet.

I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1
